# ColladaLoader access remote files

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, collada

I access the `.dae` file through the `ColladaLoader` of `three.js`, and use the local `.dae` file during the development process, which can be read smoothly.

I got an unknown error when I tested accessing `.dae` files from `gitlab` online file.

```
let loaderDae = new ColladaLoader();
   
loaderDae.load(`https://gitlab.com/po_developer/high-precision-3d-graphics-of-traditional-buildings/-/raw/master/95b69c0c-fd25-4bcf-a606-64d6619250a6/untitled.dae`, (dae: any) => {

   console.log('read successfully, something')

}, this.onProgressCallback, this.onErrorCallback)

onProgressCallback(e){
    console.log('onProgressCallback');
    console.log(e);
  }
  onErrorCallback(e){
    console.log('onErrorCallback');
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Error message:

```
onErrorCallback
architecture3-d-inner.component.ts:386 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at zone-evergreen.js:1068:1
    at FileLoader.load (three.module.js:39449:1)
    at ColladaLoader.load (ColladaLoader.js:62:1)
    at architecture3-d-inner.component.ts:333:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Architecture3DInnerComponent.loaderData (architecture3-d-inner.component.ts:328:32)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (architecture3-d-inner.component.ts:165:14)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
```

[Example file list](https://gitlab.com/po_developer/high-precision-3d-graphics-of-traditional-buildings/-/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to load the Collada asset from the above URL because it violates the CORS policy. The actual error message in the browser console looks like so:

> Access to fetch at 'https://gitlab.com/po_developer/high-precision-3d-graphics-of-traditional-buildings/-/raw/master/95b69c0c-fd25-4bcf-a606-64d6619250a6/untitled.dae' from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It's probably best if you host your assets elsewhere.

Comment: For reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/bLv0rw35/1/

Comment: I need to access a large number of models, the total size is about 500MB, it may be a better way to have cloud space, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, you can store your assets with a cloud service provider like AWS or Azure. However, depending on your traffic this will cost a lot of money so make sure you have enough budget. Using sites like GitHub is not recommended for this type of hosting (at least for production apps) since they will restrict access if the traffic gets too high.

Comment: I understand the risk, thanks! For services with low traffic, I will not read all the files at once, but will index through the list, and only open one file at a time.